# How to use build_date_utc for copyright year in mkdocs.yml

Tags: mkdocs

In my project, I want to use the current year for copyright information in mkdocs config file mkdocs.yml. According to the [mkdocs documentation](https://www.mkdocs.org/dev-guide/themes/#build_date_utc) there is `build_date_utc`. Could someone give an example of how to use it? I tried

```
copyright: "&copy; 2017 - {{ build_date_utc.year }} <a href='https://example.org' target='_blank'>Example</a>"
```

But the parameter does not render correctly in HTML.

Update: I found out that it works with a JavaScript script, like this:

```
copyright: "&copy; 2017 - <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> <a href='https://example.org' target='_blank'>Example</a>"
```

But I would still be interested in how to do it with `build_date_utc`.

Answer (score 3):

Add a simple javascript into your copyright config:

```
<p> Copyright &copy; 2022-<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> Your Name All Rights Reserved</p>
```

It will render:

[image: result]

Comment: It worked, it will be rendered as is on the browser and the current year will appear.

copyright: Copyright &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> companyname. –

Answer (score 0):

According the the MkDoc docs that you linked to `build_date_utc` is:

> A Python datetime object that represents the date and time the documentation was built in UTC.

Since it is a Python datetime object you can [format it with `strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) like any other Python datetime object.

This works for me, using mkdocs 1.2.1 and jinja2 3.0.1:

```
{% block footer %}
 &copy; {{ build_date_utc.strftime('%Y') }} 
 <a href='https://example.org' target='_blank'>Example</a>
{% endblock %}
```